# Video downloads by itself

Tags: video, media-player

I'm using a self hosted video player on a site I'm working on [here](http://lashoppe.com/wp) however, when I load the page I have the following problems:

1) On some browsers, it works as I wish, but the video starts playing by itself. I would like it to work only if I push play.

2) On some others, the video starts downloading.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The video playing itself is most likely caused by certain settings which are easily changeable. However the video downloading itself stumps me :/